# Save and XDocument to a file in a "using stream"

Tags: c#, xml, windows-store-apps, uwp

So I'm trying to do the simple task of opening an XML file, adding and XElement to it, and saving it. My curent code doesn't work:

```
Uri dataUri = new Uri("ms-appx:///XML Files/Pinouts.xml");
StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(dataUri);
using (var stream = await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
{
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(stream);
    doc.Add(new XElement(XElement.Parse(CurrentPinOut)));
    doc.Save(stream);
    stream.Flush();
}
```

As I get an "Access denied" error. I'm guessing it's a simple fix, but I haven't found anything in the last hour of searching. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot write files to *InstalledLocation* - it's *read-only*, but you surely can write files to *LocalFolder* (or other accessible locations):

```cs
StorageFile file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync("Pinouts.xml", CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);
using (var stream = await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
{
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(stream);
    doc.Add(new XElement(XElement.Parse(CurrentPinOut)));
    doc.Save(stream);
    stream.Flush();
}
```

More info about application data you will find [at MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299098.aspx).